# BB 10: Getting String Exception while returning of QByteArray

Tags: blackberry-10

I am getting exception: Exception String ""
on my code:

```
const QByteArray aa = ContactService().contactToVCard(le)
```

here le is contact

Comment: Hi, every one it get solved like this..

const QByteArray aa = ContactService().contactToVCard(le.id(), VCardPhotoEncoding::B, 1024);

Thank you for your attention.

Comment: You can put your comment in an answer to answer your own question.